# Should I add a constant $C$ in this step of doing an integral?

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

Should I add a constant $C$ in this step?

$$\begin{align*}
\int \left(\sec^2x \, dx - \sec x \tan x \, dx\right) &= \tan x - \int \sec x \tan x \, dx\\\\
\int \left(\sec^2x \, dx - \sec x \tan x \, dx\right) &= \tan x + C - \int \sec x \tan x \, dx
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Just add a constant when you are finished.

Comment: You can [see here](http://math.stackexchange.com/revisions/590a4776-f8b6-44e8-9e34-2cb7bde3e83d/view-source) how I edited your question.

[Please see here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/264) for a guide to writing math with MathJax, and [see here](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) for a guide to formatting posts with Markdown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is okay not to add one at this step: the remaining integral on the right hand side already creates an arbitrary constant of integration... and the sum of two arbitrary constants is just another arbitrary constant!

Answer (score 0):

You dont really need to add one, just add one at the very end

Comment: A day late and a dollar short. The dollar: consider $e^{\int\! f(x)\,dx}$

Comment: wait... what does that mean

Comment: The "wait till the end" is context-dependent. Sometimes it's okay, and sometimes it's not. It depends on what happens to the result of the integration on the way to a final answer. Leaving the constant of integration out until too late in the game is a common student error, so be wary of it when advising a student.